# Meteor project path from a smartpackage

Tags: node.js, meteor

I was looking for a way to look up the meteor project path from a smart package (e.g.: obtain the path of the directory where the .meteor folder is ...).
I was not able to do it using node's __dirname and __filename because somehow in meteor they are not avaiable.
Any tips ?

Answer (score 6):

As of Meteor 0.6.0 this would be:

```
var path = Npm.require('path');
var basepath = path.resolve('.');
```

Answer (score 5):

From a smartpackage (0.6.5+):

```
var path = Npm.require('path');
var base = path.resolve('.');
```

`base` in this case gets you the position of your package ..

`/User/username/projects/project/.meteor/local/programm/server/...`

.. might even be deeper

but we want

`/User/username/projects/project/`

.. so split at .meteor

```
base = base.split('.meteor')[0];
```

---

---

Or as two-liner

```
var path = Npm.require('path');
var base = path.resolve('.').split('.meteor')[0];;
```

Comment: If `meteor` is run from `yourapp/client`, then `Npm.require('path').resolve('.') will be `yourapp/client`, so you still can't find the files in your smartpackage directory.

Comment: Why would you run `meteor` in the client folder?

Comment: `Npm.require('path').resolve('.')` will give you the path of the file where it executes in. `Npm` doesn't work on the client. Also you should not work with paths, because it will all be packed on deployment afaik.

Comment: That was an example. You can run `meteor` in any subdirectory of the project, just as you can with git. Would `server` be a better example? (PS: [of course](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu?tab=tags) I know npm doesn't work on the client)

Comment: `server` would be a better example, because thats where the `Npm` command will be fired. Still, i dont get the issue here. OP was looking for "a way to look up the meteor project path from a smart package".

Comment: Let's say your `package.js` file wants to read the package version from an external file, e.g. `package.json` if you're wrapping a 3rd party library ([example](https://github.com/MeteorPackaging/hammer.js/blob/master/meteor/package.js#L7)). How would you get at the correct location of `package.json`, regardless of what directory within the project the `meteor` command was run from?

Comment: I know where you are heading but that's not the original question. The original question is about finding the __path of the meteor project__, not the path of a smartpackage.

Comment: The answer effectively finds out **the current directory** (which *usually* is the parent of `.meteor`, but that's not guaranteed), not the directory of `.meteor`. But here you go, [a clearer question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435797/how-do-i-obtain-the-path-of-a-file-in-a-meteor-package).

Comment: OP's question was "path of the directory __where__ the `.meteor` folder is". OP wasn't asking for the `.meteor` path. Every package `runs` inside a `.meteor` folder afaik (Except on deployment). Every file in your package can and should be referenced without a full path. I guess it's a _kind of_ sandboxing idea. Jumping out of that sandbox feels wrong imo.

Comment: I have no interest in jumping out of the sandbox, but [my package.js needs to find a package.json](https://github.com/MeteorPackaging/hammer.js/blob/master/meteor/package.js#L7) at ../ when testing the package locally. What I do now is create a symlink to package.json, which is weak.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Meteor 0.5.0:

```
var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
var path = require('path');
var basepath = (path.resolve('.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get access to node:

```
var __dirname = __meteor_bootstrap__.__dirname;
```

Comment: I get 'undefined' with this in Meteor 0.5.0

Answer (score 0):

You could try (only on server side)

`process.env.PWD` which returns something like that for me (OSX):

`'/Users/myusername/Desktop/myproject'`

With that command you get the root of meteor project.